# Plan for moving Sharepoint 2007 databases from SQL2005 to SQL2008

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We are going to move all databases for a Sharepoint 2007 farm from a Sql Server 2005(db_old) to a Sql Server 2008(db_new). The farm consists of one WFE and one DB.

The plan in short is:

1. Put a SQL Alias on WFE that redirects db_old queries to db_new
2. Shut down WFE
3. Detach all Sharepoint databases from db_old
4. Attach all Sharepoint databases to db_new
5. Transfer logins from from db_old to db_new
6. Fire up WFE
7. Have a beer

Will this work?